# SharePoint default page not loading, users redirected to Page Under Construction

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

So this afternoon users started reporting that they couldn't get to our SharePoint 2007 intranet site.  We set the home page via group policy for all users to the url

```
http://spsite
```

When this url is hit, SharePoint redirects to

```
http://spsite/Pages/default.aspx
```

This has been working like this for years.

Today, our remote branches are getting returned a 'Under Construction' page.  However, if these same users hit Refresh on the browser or type in the

```
http://spsite/pages/default.aspx
```

they get there without issue.

Our local users are not seeing this problem at all.  This tells me there has to be some kind of DNS resolution problem.  I'm not much of a SharePoint guy, so I'm at a loss.

Has anyone seen this behavior before?  What would be my first step in trying to figure out where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting the resolution for this and the theory behind the issue.

There were a few things that happened in our environment that lead to this 'Perfect Storm' scenario.

At some point in the day, our SharePoint site became unresponsive.  Users hitting the site at that time then got back an odd response from the server.  It seems that somehow IIS had two sites listening on port 80, both with a wildcard binding.  The first site was the SharePoint site, the second one was the default site.  When the SharePoint site failed to respond, IIS then went to the Default Site.  Since this site hadn't been set up, the 'Site Under Construction' page was returned (IIS6 on Windows 2003 server).

This was odd in itself.  However, what happened later is just as bizarre. An IISReset fixed the problem that the SharePoint site was having.  As a result, the SharePoint site was again available.  However, anyone that had hit the url when it was down had a cached the iisstart.htm page.  It appears that when their browser was checking the URL, they were getting a 304 from the server.  So the request never made it all the way into the sharepoint site, which actually returns a 302 redirect.

So, for all these users, we had to clear the cache on their machine and this then allowed the to get back to the SharePoint site.